# How to produce pairwise combinations of all character pairs in a string

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, biopython

I have this string

```
s = 'AGGCTTAGGATTCAAA'
```

I want to make tuples using first two characters with next two, one by one, like this:

```
('AGGC', 1), ('AGTT', 1/2), ('AGAG', 1/3), ('AGGA', 1/4), 
('AGTT', 1/5), ('AGCA', 1/6), ('AGAA', 1/7),
```

...then the second two with the next two:

```
('GCTT', 1), ('GCAG', 1/2), ('GCGA', 1/3), ('GCTT', 1/4),
('GCCA', 1/5), ('GCAA', 1/6),
```

then the third two and so on:

```
('TTAG', 1), ('TTGA', 1/2), ('TTTT', 1/3), ('TTCA', 1/4). ('TTAA', 1/5),
('AGGA', 1), ('AGTT', 1/2), ('AGCA', 1/3), ('AGAA', 1/4), ('GATT', 1),
('GACA', 1/2), ('GAAA', 1/3), ('TTCA', 1), ('TTAA', 1/2), ('CAAA', 1)
```

I tried to achieve it like this:

```py
s = 'AGGCTTAGGATTCAAA'
output = [
    (s[i:i+2] + c[:2], 1 /(idx + 1))
    for i in range(0, len(s) -2, )
    for idx, c in enumerate(s[i+2:])
]
```

But this gives me tuples of three characters, not four.

How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: Convert the string to a list/tuple of pairs.  Now you can use itertools permutations and/or combinations to make your combos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not far from what you needed. Most important, you need to step by 2 characters (using the third argument of `range`):

```
output = [
    (s[i:i+2] + s[j:j+2], 1 / (idx + 1))
    for i in range(0, len(s), 2)
    for idx, j in enumerate(range(i + 2, len(s), 2))
]
```

To see the fractions in `1/x` format, you could use `fractions`, like this:

```
from fractions import Fraction

s = 'AGGCTTAGGATTCAAA'

output = [
    (s[i:i+2] + s[j:j+2], Fraction(1, idx + 1))
    for i in range(0, len(s), 2)
    for idx, j in enumerate(range(i + 2, len(s), 2))
]

for pair in output:
    print(*pair)
```

This outputs:

```
AGGC 1
AGTT 1/2
AGAG 1/3
AGGA 1/4
AGTT 1/5
AGCA 1/6
AGAA 1/7
GCTT 1
GCAG 1/2
GCGA 1/3
GCTT 1/4
GCCA 1/5
GCAA 1/6
TTAG 1
TTGA 1/2
TTTT 1/3
TTCA 1/4
TTAA 1/5
AGGA 1
AGTT 1/2
AGCA 1/3
AGAA 1/4
GATT 1
GACA 1/2
GAAA 1/3
TTCA 1
TTAA 1/2
CAAA 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you are asking:

```
import itertools

s = 'AGGCTTAGGATTCAAA'

lst = [s[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(s),2)]

for c in itertools.combinations(lst,2):
    print(''.join(c))
```

Output:

```
AGGC
AGTT
AGAG
AGGA
AGTT
AGCA
AGAA
GCTT
GCAG
GCGA
GCTT
GCCA
GCAA
TTAG
TTGA
TTTT
TTCA
TTAA
AGGA
AGTT
AGCA
AGAA
GATT
GACA
GAAA
TTCA
TTAA
CAAA
```